# What is the reason for the discrepancy between /proc/[pid]/status:RssAnon and /proc/[pid]/smaps_rollup:Anonymous?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, procfs

I regularly notice discrepancies between the numbers given for `RssAnon` in `/proc/[pid]/status` and for `Anonymous` in `/proc/[pid]/smaps_rollup`.  I also looked at `RssShmem` in `/proc/[pid]/status`, but that did not help to explain the difference.  For example:

```
status:Name: tail
status:RssAnon:          72 kB
status:RssShmem:          0 kB

smaps_rollup:Anonymous:  92 kB
```

In the system that I analyse (which has a 4.14 kernel), such discrepancies are common.  There are also cases where the numbers match, but this is not quite as common.

I found a lot of pages where the contents of `/proc/[pid]/status`, `/proc/[pid]/smaps` and `/proc/[pid]/smaps_rollup` are explained.  There was, however, never a conclusive explanation for the difference.  An answer from rr- came closest (actually, `statm` and `smaps` were discussed here): https://stackoverflow.com/a/30799817/5747415, as it was based on the analysis of the kernel code for the generation of `smaps` and `statm`.  It ended with a (plausible, but unconfirmed) assumption that `smaps` calculates its data in a reliable but time-consuming way by actually iterating over the memory regions, whereas the information in `statm` is based on counters (in this case `MM_ANONPAGES`) that are continuously updated at lots of different places - which might lead to inconsistencies.

Can someone provide some founded explanation for the discrepancies?  Are they intended and the meaning of the values is different?  Or is it actually a bug?  Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plausible theory you mention is true. The man pages have been updated: https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-mm/msg230450.html

> Since 34e55232e59f7b19050267a05ff1226e5cd122a5 (introduced back in
> v2.6.34), Linux uses per-thread RSS counters to reduce cache contention on
> the per-mm counters. With a 4K page size, that means that you can end up
> with the counters off by up to 252KiB* per thread.

(*this precise number is not strictly accurate, see thread for details)